# Question closed for being a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, exact-duplicates

I just opened the following new question about **Mass Effect 3**:

> [Which Mass Effect 2 DLCs are relevant for Mass Effect 3's story?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91893/which-mass-effect-2-dlcs-are-relevant-for-mass-effect-3s-story)

It was immediately closed for being a duplicate of this question:

> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52478/will-the-decisions-made-in-mass-effect-dlcs-carry-into-me3

Which in itself was closed for being a duplicate of this question:

> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50947/what-side-quests-dlc-and-achievements-should-i-make-sure-to-complete-in-prepar

Which in itself was closed for being a duplicate of this question:

> [To what extent do your choices in Mass Effect influence the story in Mass Effect 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/to-what-extent-do-your-choices-in-mass-effect-influence-the-story-in-the-sequel)

Which was actually asked long before Mass Effect 3 was released, and in fact was only referring to **Mass Effect 2**.

Something has gone awry here.

Comment: I thought there was a feature, or at least a feature request, that prevented this from happening

Comment: I misread the target question, sorry!

Comment: **Closeception!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second and third questions were closed mainly because they were asked *before* the game was released. I have no idea why they were closed as exact duplicate, especially the older one. I have deleted them.

I agree your question is not about ME2, so I have reopened it.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to see something resolved quickly!